# Get user ID from JWT (JSON web token)

Tags: json, swift, jwt

I am using the plugin to authenticate WordPress using api-rest : [JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/)

From the request to the server I get the following answer:

```
{
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvbWlob3N0Lm9yZ1wvcHJ1ZWJhcyIsImlhdCI6MTU1MzcyNDM4MSwibmJmIjoxNTUzNzI0MzgxLCJleHAiOjE1NTQzMjkxODEsImRhdGEiOnsidXNlciI6eyJpZCI6IjIifX19.rgi5Q2c8RCoHRp-lJiJN8xQaOavn9T_q8cmf8v1-57o",
    "user_email": "abc@test.com",
    "user_nicename": "test",
    "user_display_name": "Test"
}
```

So far everything works fine, but I need to know the user ID.

I have read that the token is coded in base64 and within this is the ID. Trying to decode, I see if the ID that I need is there.

In swift with this function I decode the token, but I can not get the dictionary ID.

```
func decode(_ token: String) -> [String: AnyObject]? {
    let string = token.components(separatedBy: ".")
    let toDecode = string[1] as String


    var stringtoDecode: String = toDecode.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "+") // 62nd char of encoding
    stringtoDecode = stringtoDecode.replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: "/") // 63rd char of encoding
    switch (stringtoDecode.utf16.count % 4) {
    case 2: stringtoDecode = "\(stringtoDecode)=="
    case 3: stringtoDecode = "\(stringtoDecode)="
    default: // nothing to do stringtoDecode can stay the same
        print("")
    }
    let dataToDecode = Data(base64Encoded: stringtoDecode, options: [])
    let base64DecodedString = NSString(data: dataToDecode!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

    var values: [String: AnyObject]?
    if let string = base64DecodedString {
        if let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue, allowLossyConversion: true) {
            values = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String : AnyObject]
        }
    }
    return values
}
```

The dictionary that returns this function is:

```
["iss": https://myhost.me/test, "exp": 1554235730, "nbf": 1553630930, "iat": 1553630930, "data": {
    user =     {
        id = 2;
    };
}]
```

How do I get the ID from this dictionary?

Comment: you can easily extract by JSON parsing from your `values` var. ```if let user = values["data"] as [String: Any], let id = user["id"] as Int { return id }```

Comment: Why do you append `=` at the end of `base64` string? It won't do nothing `Data(base64Encoded:)`. At least I haven't seen it resulting in `nil` without `=` padding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is pretty *unswifty*.

Basically don't use `NS...` classes in Swift if there is a native equivalent and a JSON dictionary is always value type (`[String:Any]`).

I recommend to add an `Error` enum, make the function *can throw*, decode the serialized token with `Decodable` and return the `Token` instance on success

```
struct Token : Decodable {
    let data : UserData

    struct UserData  : Decodable {
        let user : User

        struct User  : Decodable {
            let id : String
        }
    }
}
```

You are encouraged to keep the parameter label in the method declaration

```
enum TokenError : Error {
    case invalidJWTFormat, invalidBase64EncodedData
}

func decode(token: String) throws -> Token {
    let components = token.components(separatedBy: ".")
    guard components.count == 3 else { throw TokenError.invalidJWTFormat }
    var decodedString = components[1]
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "+")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: "/")

    while decodedString.utf16.count % 4 != 0 { 
        decodedString += "=" 
    }
    guard let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: decodedString) else { throw TokenError.invalidBase64EncodedData }
    return try JSONDecoder().decode(Token.self, from: decodedData)
}
```

and call it

```
do {
   let userID = try decode(token: "eyJ0eXAi.....").data.user.id
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: Valid `JWT` contains not just `> 1` sections, but `three` sections, no more and no less. _Three shalt be the number thou shalt count, and the number of the counting shall be three. Four shalt thou not count, nor either count thou two, excepting that thou then proceed to three. Five is right out._

Comment: @user28434 Thanks for heads-up. I updated the answer.

Comment: And to be honest, just getting data from JWT without validating it's signature just nullifies essence of JWT. Whatever garbage payload from whatever source will do that way. And https://jwt.io lists like 4 different that will do _most_ of the checks and verifications for you.